# Embedding inside the model vs outside the model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, word-embedding

What is the difference between using the embedding layer inside the model and outside the model? I can build the embedding layer into the model:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=1000, output_dim=64, input_length=10))
...
model.fit(features, target ...)
```

I can also use embdedding outside the model to generate embedded data and then feed it into the model:

```
embedding_encoder = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=1000, output_dim=64)
embedded_features = embedding_encoder(features)
...

model.fit(embedded_features, target ...)
```

Does it mean that if I use embedding outside the model, embedding parameters are not learned during the training?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does it mean that if I use embedding outside the model, embedding
> parameters are not learned during the training?

The dense vector representations assigned from an `Embedding` layer are generally only trainable when setting `trainable=True`. It's entirely up to you how you want to preprocess your data yourself and how much you want to leave to the `Embedding` layer. Usually, if you are working on a NLP task, you can add a `StringLookup` or `TextVectorization` layer prior to adding an `Embedding` layer that allows you to preprocess your texts and train them in an elegant way without any "manual" steps.

**Generally**:

Each integer value fed to an `Embedding` layer is mapped to a unique N-dimensional vector representation, where N is chosen by you. These vector representations are, by default, drawn from a uniform distribution. The `Embedding` layer inherits from `tf.keras.layers.Layer` which contains the trainable parameter.

I think it could make sense to generate embedding data outside your model if you are, for example, using pretrained context-sensitive vectors and you do not want to update their values during training. But again, it’s all up to you.

Comment: I can't find the parameter `trainable` in `tf.keras.layers.Embedding`. Does it mean that in the second case, my embedding vector contains random numbers? I would always train the embedding layer in this case, but I see many examples where embedding is outside the model (mainly if you have different data types and multiple inputs models).

Comment: Updated answer..

Comment: In this [keras example](https://keras.io/examples/structured_data/movielens_recommendations_transformers/) they use embeddings outside the model (see `encode_input_features` function). It would make sense to build it into the model. Why don't they do it?

Comment: Hmm I am not sure why the author decided on those design patterns. Maybe it was more convenient and efficient